# Installing CloudBees SDK and running bees command first time - errors downloading plugins

Tags: cloudbees

I have installed the [cloudbees SDK](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK) and am now running the bees command the first time..

I see this:

```
Installing plugin: org.cloudbees.sdk.plugins:ant-plugin:LATEST

You have not created a CloudBees configuration profile, let's create one now... 
Enter your CloudBees account email address: XXX 
Enter your CloudBees account password:

ERROR: Failed to install org.cloudbees.sdk.plugins:ant-plugin:LATEST
```

And thus, an unable to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases if you just run the bees command again, it will download the plugins again (plugins are only fetched the first time they are needed). If you are on a VPN this can cause some temporary issues as well.

You can also add the  -v flag to get more verbose messages from the command line.